# What are all the reasons for which gods/Devas are depicted as fighting each other?

Tags: gods

As per me, mostly it seems like "boon conflict" someone is given a boon by God A for protection and God B wants to attack him for something else.  classic case is the banasura story - he picks a fight with krishna but siva is boon-bound to defend him and a war allegedly happens between siva and krishna bexause of that.

What are the other reasons for which two or more gods fight with one another? Do the reasons indicate a definite pattern?

Comment: Few instances of boon conflict are discussed in this post https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22525/12304 However, can you please give one example in your Question (which gods are depicted as fighting each other) to make it more clear..

Comment: Thanks for the Edit but still **It's unclear what you're asking**...

Comment: god vs god, god vs deva and deva vs deva fights have been recorded.  each conflict has a reason - is there a pattern in these reasons?

Comment: if your aim is to close the question do it if you can.  what gives you the right to be derisive? @YDS

Comment: So u mean no body should ask clarification on your questions/answers? If it's not clear then people asks clarification on them.. now u only said "is there a pattern"..what does that mean in hinduism SE..??? Banasura's story is described here https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/63 ..what kind of pattern you are looking for???

Comment: I have edited the Q.. see if it's ok or not..@SK