# What is the story of the King Nipata?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

What is the story of the king called Nipata (who proved to be an equal warrior to Ravan)? Is this story mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana? Uttara Kanda?

I found it on Krittivbasi Ramayan only.

> Ravana then let Vasuki go.
>   Ravana continuing came across kings whom he easily defeated in battle. He then across a king called Nipata and started fighting him. None could defeat the other. Brahma then appeared there and said it would be impossible to defeat one another, as both had been blessed with boons.
>   Both took leave of each other.

Source - http://babubanglaramayanretell.blogspot.com/2016/10/ravana-in-nether-world.html

Answer (score 3):

The story is mentioned in [UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-23), After defeating Vasuki and before the war with Varuna (or his sons), Ravana had a war with Nivatakavachas (Nipata seems their king) which was resolved by Lord Brahma himself.

> And arriving at Bhogavati the city governed by **Vasuki**, he brought the Nagas under subjection.
>
> And then, delighted, bent his course to the palace Manimayi There dwelt the **Nivatakavachas**", who had obtained boons. Those Daityas were possessed of prowess and endowed with strength, carrying various weapons, breathing high spirits and invincible in battle.
>
> And the Danavas and Rakshasas growing enraged fell to raving each other with darts and tridents, Kulicas and axes and Patticas. And as they faught one entire year passed away and neither side obtained victory or was worsted.
>
> And then that way of the triune sphere, that God, the undeteriorating Great father, swiftly presented himself on the scene mounted on his excellent car.

And making the Nivatakavachas desist from battle the ancient great father (Lord Brahma) spoke in clear words:

> "Even the Devas and the Asuras are not able to vanquish this Ravana in battle; nor can the Danavas backed by the Devas can destroy you. Do you therefore turn your minds to making friends with the Rakshasa. All interests are forsooth the common possession of friends."

This was one of the special cases of boon conflicts as discussed in this post:

[Is there any mention of boon deadlock in scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22212/is-there-any-mention-of-boon-deadlock-in-scriptures)

> Thereat Ravana made friends with the Nivatakavachas in the presence of Fire ;and then rejoiced greatly. And duly honored (by them) Dasanana passed there a year, without any feeling of that place being different from his own home: and spent his time agreeably. And having learnt there an hundred sorts of illusion, he directed his course to Rasatala, searching for the city of the lord of waters.

Comment: i am unable to mention you or tag your username. But i have another question. Why would Ravan leave his own kingdom of lanka for a whole entire year and stay with the Nivatakavachas? He gained alot of things out of his travel like learning one hundred types of illusions. But why would he leave his precious lanka? Who was ruling lanka in his place?

Comment: @ThePhone999 This Patala Vijaya episode was quite longer...after this 1 year he had a fight with Kalkeyas (where he killed his own brother in law)..then with Varuna's sons..then he met Bali Maharaj..etc..but Ravana stayed at other places too... And when Ravana was out, some other incidents also happened parallely, for an instance, a deamon named Madhu abducted Kumbhnashi bcz Kumbhkarna was sleeping, Vibhishan was performing some rituals (so couldn't fight), MeghanAda was performing sacrifices...

Comment: YDS *But my question still remains unanswered sir. Who was the king of lanka while Ravan was away conquering lands? A king cannot leave his kingdom unattended with no one to be the ruler of it (as his representative), does Valmiki ever mention anything about this?*

Comment: @ThePhone999 Kumbhkarna, MeghanAda and Vibhishan stayed in Lanka..nothing much is revealed other than this..Vibhishan might have acted as Ravana's representative..

Comment: Last mistake Nipata was not mentioned in this text (the quote you gave) so i don't understand how you can say he was the king of the Nivatakavacas?