# If two kings perform a sacrifice which yields victory, and fight each other, who wins?

Tags: vedas, rituals, yajna, shatapatha-brahmana, sacrifice

The Vedas have sacrifices which, when performed, yield guaranteed victory in the next battle fought.

If two kings perform that sacrifice and fight each other, who wins?

Comment: I was about to ask a similar question.If two kings who pray the same God(e.g Lord Shiva) , both have attained the kripa of Lord Shiva,fight against each other,then who wins.

Comment: 1. The sacrifice might be interrupted for the one who is less worthy... 2. If both complete the sacrifice then it will be the case of [boon deadlock](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22525/12304) ...

Comment: @YDS I also think that too. Depending on their karma or who is more worthy or unworthy, the sacrifice may be interfered with by those Devas who are the presiding deities of that sacrifice, since the fruit must be given to those who complete the sacrifice.