# Why didn't anyone ask for infinite wishes for a boon?

Tags: boon

We know that if one person does a lot of Tapasya, then he can get a boon from Bhagawan Bholenath. We also know Ravana also once got a boon from Shiva ji. There are many times that even Lord Vishnu gives boons.

Let's say a very cunning person does a lot of Tapasya Bhagawan Sri Rama, and consequently Lord Rama appears after many years of the man's Tapasya and asks the man to wish for anything.

This cunning man decides to ask for infinite wishes. Would God fullfil his wish? What are the consequences of such a wish? And why hasn't anyone (for example evil Ravan) never asked for such a boon?

Comment: " And why hasn't anyone (for example evil Ravan) never asked for such a boon?" I will give you a hint. What is the one of the most important aspects of the material world?

Comment: @Wikash_ I don't know the most important aspect of the material world. Is it it's temporariness? Or the law of Karma? I am not sure. Maybe you can tell me.

Comment: Think about. The demons aren't stupid they could have wished for a lot things. Like an infinite large army to protect themselves but they did not. Why?

Comment: @Wikash_ You can use [chat] if you are discussing or chatting with OP. Comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: Even to a single boon offered by God, he keeps a check on that boon so that any misuse they can use that and kill that person.

Comment: God has Ishita siddhi, which means whatever God thinks comes into reality.  If God grants someone that, he/she lose individual existence just like a drop of soul disappears in an Ocean of God. If not, he/she will destroy the creation of God as human is like a child and is not Omniscient, so doesnot know the consequences of his wishes.

Comment: I will do tapasya and ask for that wish:) just kidding!!!! There are instances where people have asked for becoming amar and have been rejected so......it is possible that such a boon is rejected.....further we are just puppets in his hands......whom are we trying to be over-smart with:)

Comment: related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22525/12304

Comment: @Wikash_ to answer: why wouldn't ask for infinite boons, the answer is:  it leads to perpetual dissatisfaction perhaps..

Comment: @blue_ego it is strange that it has not been asked by anyone including demons who ask almost everything. Maybe it is a mistake in the scriptures? I do not think dissatisfaction has anything to do with it since demons ask boons which almost always leads to bad things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why hasn't anyone (for example evil Ravan) never asked for such a boon?**

Ravana asked such boon. As per, [UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-10), he asked the boon of **immortality**:

> O Reverend one, creatures have no other fear than (that of) death ;and enemy there is none that is like unto death. Therefore immortality is even what I crave for.

But Lord Brahma denied that. Later he asked a boon of **incapable of being slain by Surpas, Nagas, Yakshas, Daityas, Danavas, Rakshasas and Devas**.

Similarly, Kumbhkarna wanted to ask Indrasana or Nirdaya (for the destruction of the Devas) in boon but gods knew that if he would be awake, he can eat lot of people so gods asked goddess Sarasvati to help in this matter and coming under the influence of goddess Sarasvati, Kumbhkarna asked Nidrasana or Nidra in boon from Lord Brahma.

But Vibhishana was not a cunning man and he got immortality in boon from Lord Brahma.

Similarly, there are many instances where boon of immortality were not awarded to cunning demons and they were asked to request another similar boon. They asked a boon so that their death is near to impossible but not impossible.

However, Vṛkāsura succeeded in getting such boon. As per, [SB 10.88](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/88):

> Vṛka said, “May death come to whomever I touch upon the head with my hand.”

Lord Shiva granted him this boon. And, to test the boon, Vṛka then tried to put his hand on the Lord Shiva’s head. Later, Lord Vishnu somehow tricked Vṛka to test the boon by putting his hand on his own head and as soon as Vṛka put his hand on his own head, he died.

**The cunning man decides to ask for infinite wishes. Would God fullfil his wish?**

The answer would be most probably NO. As stated in above Ravana's example, the God would ask him to request another similar boon with some loopholes. Or if a cunning man succeed in getting such boon then somehow some way would be found to handle such cunning man.

Comment: This isn't an answer. You have answered the question of immortality not infinite boons.

Comment: This answer is not about infinite boons, but deals only with the boon of immortality. Also, “**Vibhishana got the boon of immortality**” where did you get this from?

Comment: @HayagreevRam “Vibhishana got the boon of immortality”--it's mentioned in the same chapter of UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana which is linked in the answer..same chapter describe about the boon of Kumbhakarna and Ravana..

Comment: @YDS It is a well-known fact that Uttara Kanda of Ramayana is interpolated and was not a part of the original Ramayana by Valmiki. Can you provide a source from somewhere else in the Ramayana to substantiate the fact?

Comment: @HayagreevRam No need to provide any source...Vibhishana is in the list of immortals is already discussed on the site..See Qs with [chiranjivi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chiranjivi) tag...Also, Uttar Kanda is not banned on the site, we can answer from Uttar kanda..

Answer (score 4):

The OP put forward so many questions:

> This cunning man decides to ask for infinite wishes.
>
> Would God fullfil his wish?
>
> What are the consequences of such a wish?
>
> And why hasn't anyone (for example evil Ravan) never asked for such a boon?

Answer to these questions will be a little bit lengthy and complex also.

Sri Krishna says in B.G., as follows:

> कामैस्तैस्तैर्हृतज्ञानाः प्रपद्यन्तेऽन्यदेवताः।
>
> तं तं नियममास्थाय प्रकृत्या नियताः स्वया।।7.20।।
>
> Being robbed of their wisdom by innumerable desires [and] being controlled by their own nature, persons take refuge in other deities by following one or the other religious regulations.
>
> अन्तवत्तु फलं तेषां तद्भवत्यल्पमेधसाम्।
>
> देवान्देवयजो यान्ति मद्भक्ता यान्ति मामपि।।7.23।।
>
> But, that fruit of those men of poor intellect is finite. Those, who perform sacrifices, aiming at the gods, go to gods, and My devotees go to Me.

Apparently, very easy to understand, but these words carry very subtle meaning.  Remember that these words have come from a **Yogi of the highest order**.

---

A few issues, to the extent of my understanding, can be discussed.

Consider the sloka 7.20 from B.G., mentioned above.

> Being robbed of their wisdom by innumerable desires ......

Don't conclude that the Almighty God is a Fool enough to grant boons, without any controls?  Never does it occur.  **A boon *asked by a desire* carries its own seeds of destruction.**

However, brilliant a person like Ravana might be, the Creator will think many steps ahead of him.  It is for sure.

The devotee shall get his desires fulfilled, but with some riders.

How brilliantly, Hiranyakashipu asked boons Brahma, for avoiding death, but ultimately met his end in the hands of Nrisimha.