# Instances of deity granting improved version of boon

Tags: scripture, boon, savitri

In broad, one can classify the boons granted by deities to devotees into three categories:

1. Boons that enhance the intention of a devotee
2. Boons that diminish the intention of a devotee  [1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35269/why-didnt-anyone-ask-for-infinite-wishes-for-a-boon) [2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a027.htm)
3. Boons that exactly match the intention of the devotee

This question deals with instances of type 1. I am aware of the following instance that stands as an example of type 1 in which Ma Savitri grants herself as the daughter to Aswapati although he asked for a normal son.

Consider the following instance of Savitri granting a boon not exactly asked by the Aswapati. I can say that Savitri granted more than what was asked for

> And with the object of raising offspring, he observed rigid vows and
> began to live upon frugal fare, having recourse to the Brahmacharya
> mode of life, and restraining his senses. And that best of kings,
> (daily) offering ten thousand oblations to the fire, recited Mantras
> in honour of Savitri and ate temperately at the sixth hour. And he
> passed eighteen years, practising such vows. Then when the eighteen
> years were full, Savitri was pleased (with him). And O king, issuing
> with great delight, in embodied form, from the Agnihotra fire, the
> goddess showed herself to that king. And intent on conferring boons,
> she spoke these words unto the monarch, 'I have been gratified, O
> king, with thy Brahmacharya practices, thy purity and self-restraint
> and observance of vows, and all thy endeavours and veneration! Do
> thou, O mighty king. O Aswapati, ask for the boon that thou desirest!
> Thou ought, however, by no means show any disregard for virtue.'
> Thereat Aswapati said, '**It is with the desire of attaining virtue that
> I have been engaged in this task. O goddess, may many sons be born
> unto me worthy of my race! If thou art pleased with me, O goddess, I
> ask for this boon. The twice-born ones have assured me that great
> merit lieth in having offspring!**' Savitri replied, '**O king, having
> already learnt this thy intention, I had spoken unto that lord, the
> Grandsire, about thy sons. Through the favour granted by the
> Self-create, there shall speedily be born unto thee on earth a
> daughter of great energy. It behoveth thee not to make any reply.
> Well-pleased, I tell thee this at the command of the Grandsire.**'
>
> "Markandeya said, 'Having accepted Savitri's words and saying, 'So be
> it!' the king again gratified her and said, 'May this happen soon!' On
> Savitri vanishing away, the monarch entered his own city.

I want to know a similar instance in which a deity enhances the intent of the devotee and grants a bigger boon than what a devotee asks for. What can be another such instance?