# What is the scriptural support for interpolations, ignoring evidence from boon stories and quotations?

Tags: interpolation

Many Hindus believe in interpolations in scriptures. However, all the evidence of it I've seen comes from boon stories ([which I don't think are real](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50030/21895)) and quotations of untrustworthy people (which I am always suspicious of). Does anyone have evidence of interpolation not using these, ideally not using sectarian logic that doesn't work with a comprehensive overview of scripture?

Comment: How did you figure out that boon stories are not real?

Comment: @Wikash_ Because some stories involving boons make no sense if they are real https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50030/21895

Comment: @Wikash_ Also a bunch of small things like boon logic being inconsistent and lack of people who would be clearly able to achieve boons not getting them.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.